# What is the ideal focal length for videography?

Tags: lens, video

While this forum is about photography, most of the DSLRs today can be use for videography.  What is the ideal focal length when doing a VTR or Video-Tape Recording? I'll be doing a video presentation with some interviews using my DSLR.  I've heard that some people prefers using semi wide angle lens rather than standard 35mm or 50mm to create a wide area effect.  Meanwhile others are also suggesting an 85mm f/1.8 to avoid distorting the subjects.  So what lens should I go for? Should I go for semi wide angle or a semi telephoto? Or a standard focal length will do? Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Videography questions are explicitly off-topic here - please post them at avp.stackexchance.com instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same as photographing people, there isn't such thing as an ideal focal length - if there was all the camera companies wouldn't have to produce such an extensive lens lineup.

If you want to show a person in the environment you use a wider lens, if you want to focus just on one person you use a longer lens. If you want a specific effect you use whatever will produce this effect (for example, shallow DOF -> long, exaggerated perspective -> wide) and of course physical constraints of the shooting environment (have to place the camera far away -> long, don't have room and have to be really close -> wide)